# Neo4j - Complex cypher query - needs outer join

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j graph database, and I am trying to build a complex cypher query

I have the following nodes and relations:

**Nodes**:

- Customer node
- Brand node
- Segment node (which has a "MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth" property)
- Reservation node

**Relations**:

- Each customer is **segmented** to a segment
- customers can have a **cust_reserved** relation with a reservation
- Each reservation is **related** to a brand

I want to get ***count of customers*** which are eligible for a new reservation for certain brand.

so, I need to count reservations for each customer for the given brand and compare with MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth for this customer's segment.

note that customers who don't have reservations should be counted also

Thanks for your support.

**EDIT 1**

after trying Michael first query, query is :

```
PROFILE MATCH (c:Customer)
// also count customers without reservations (make this match optional)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:CUST_RESERVED]->(r:Reservation)-[:RESERVATION_FOR]->(b:brand {BRAND_ID: "3"})
// count reservations by brand and customers
WITH c, b, count(*) as reservations
MATCH (c)-[:SEGMENTED]->(s:segment)
WHERE reservations < s.max_sms_per_month
// aggregate count customers per brand
RETURN b.NAME, count(distinct c) as customers
```

Query result:
[image: query result]

the result is unexpected, I want to get eligible customer for "Honda" brand , the result is only 5 (which were already reserved for Honda before but still eligible because they didn't reach the maximum yet) , the result should be 998734 (all customers)

Query profile: [Query profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyddv.png)

Data set: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdmw5khwmjk12ap/GarphDatabaseLocation.zip?dl=0)
Needed query in SQL: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cheztzj5d110unx/query.sql?dl=0)

**EDIT 2**

Michael second query worked like a charm in around 20 sec, thank you Michael
I need to include some date logic to check reservations during certain reservations please :)

Comment: Try to create an constraint / index for `:brand(BRAND_ID)` (note you should fix the spelling to `:Brand(brandId)`

Comment: As you group by brand name (which is what I expected as you said "eligible for a brand").

Answer (score 3):

You already spelled it out, please see our online guide for how you'd go from your use-case question: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/

So your patterns are

```
(:Customer)-[:IS_SEGMENTED]->(:Segment {MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth:int})
(:Customer)-[:HAS_RESERVED]->(:Reservation)
(:Reservation)-[:FOR_BRAND]->(:Brand)
```

Your question:

> 1. I want to get count of customers which are eligible for a new reservation for certain brand.
> 2. so, I need to count reservations for each customer for the given brand and compare with MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth for this customer's segment.
> 3. note that customers who don't have reservations should be counted also

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
// also count customers without reservations (make this match optional)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_RESERVED]->(r:Reservation)-[:FOR_BRAND]->(b:Brand)
// count reservations by brand and customers
WITH c, b, count(*) as reservations
MATCH (c)-[:IS_SEGMENTED]->(s:Segment)
WHERE s.MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth < reservations
// aggregate count customers per brand
RETURN b.name, count(distinct c) as customers
```

"as what should customers be counted without reservations" as 0 ?

#### Update: Query for non-optional reservations

Question: which brand would customers without a reservation be related to / checkt against? As the reservations-count is 0 then MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth would have to be -1 for those to be ever selected? So we can also just make it non-optional? Please also share the query plan you get with a PROFILE prefix.

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[:HAS_RESERVED]->(r:Reservation)-[:FOR_BRAND]->(b:Brand)
// count reservations by brand and customers
WITH c, b, count(*) as reservations
MATCH (c)-[:IS_SEGMENTED]->(s:Segment)
WHERE s.MaxReservationsPerBrandPerMonth < reservations
// aggregate count customers per brand
RETURN b.name, count(distinct c) as customers
```

#### Update 2, Query Optimization Attempt

Your query is a graph global one, so it will touch many many paths, you have at least 10M db-hits already.

I'd probably change that query then a bit:

I'm not 100% sure anymore though how brand comes into play here:
Also a bit hard to do without a dataset!

```
MATCH (b:brand {BRAND_ID: "3"})
MATCH (c:Customer) 
WITH b,c, size((c)-[:CUST_RESERVED]->()) as total_res
WITH b,c,total_res, 
     case when total_res > 0 then last(nodes(head((c)-[:SEGMENTED]->(:segment)))).max_sms_per_month else 10 end as max_sms_per_month,
     case when total_res > 0 then size((c)-[:CUST_RESERVED]->()-[:RESERVATION_FOR]->(b)) else 0 end as brand_res
WHERE total_res = 0 OR total_res < max_sms_per_month OR brand_res < max_sms_per_month
// TODO what to do with reservations by brand?   
RETURN b.NAME, count(distinct c) as customers
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, It worked like a charm, I only changed it to be reservations < MaxReservations , I think that was a typo.
But for 1 million customers with only 10 of them reserved, it took about 111726 ms , is that normal ?

Comment: Michael, I am afraid there's a type of cartesian product here, I executed the query once more and Neo4j server hangs

Comment: It's a global query, if you prefix your query with PROFILE you see how many paths it finds. Would it be possible for you to share the database with me personallly? michael at neo4j.com

Comment: The problem might be your "optional" checking. We could change that by using a UNION, I updated the answer to reflect the alternative.

Comment: Thank you @Michael again, let me clarify more, the case that I am working on application that sends advertisement sms's to customers for different brands, and the constraint is, according to customer's segment , they cannot receive more sms's than defined in their segment for each brand, So when I start a new campaign for certain brand, I want to run query to get number of eligible customers to receive sms for this brand, I hope you got me , I will reply again tomorrow sorry it's 1 am here :)

Comment: Hi @Michael , I added the executed query, result and query profile, please check them

Comment: I added a more optimized query, a bit hard to do without a dataset

Comment: Thank you Michael, it worked well, I added the dataset for you along with needed query in SQL, can you help please adding date logic like SQL query ?